Building the URDF of robot with multiple parent links
I have a mechanical structure where there is a plate mounted on a cylinder. This cylinder can rotate on its z-axis. This plate is also attached to a sort of lifter, so that the plate can be raised and lowered. At last, this plate can also slide horizontally. From a kinematic point of view, in the URDF, how can I assign the parents and the children links into the joints? What's the minimum number of joints I need to execute all the movements?
EDIT 1: Here's a sketch of the structure. I don't know how useful it can be I can't provide anything more detailed.

I have the table T (in red). This table can be placed on the yellow column, such column can rotate along its z-axis. Moreover, the table T can slide along the green binaries. This sliding movement can be initiated if and only if the table is first raised by the brown lifter L.
Now my URDF looks like this:


<!--links-->
<xacro:rulliera name="base" origin_xyz="0 0 0" origin_rpy="1.5708 0 0" mass="1" ixx="0.1" ixy="0.1" ixz="0.1" iyy="0.1" iyz="0.1" izz="0.1"
                file_dae="package://rulliera/visual/infrastruttura.dae" file_stl="package://rulliera/collision/infrastruttura.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>

<xacro:rulliera name="rotary" origin_xyz="0 0.023 -0.372" origin_rpy="1.5708 0 0" mass="1" ixx="0.1" ixy="0.1" ixz="0.1" iyy="0.1" iyz="0.1" izz="0.1"
                file_dae="package://rulliera/visual/rotary.dae" file_stl="package://rulliera/collision/rotary.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>

<xacro:rulliera name="slider" origin_xyz="0 0.415715 0.3455" origin_rpy="-1.5708 0 0" mass="1" ixx="0.1" ixy="0.1" ixz="0.1" iyy="0.1" iyz="0.1" izz="0.1"
                file_dae="package://rulliera/visual/piastra.dae" file_stl="package://rulliera/collision/piastra.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>

<xacro:rulliera name="lifter" origin_xyz="0 0 0" origin_rpy="0 0 0" mass="1" ixx="0.1" ixy="0.1" ixz="0.1" iyy="0.1" iyz="0.1" izz="0.1"
                file_dae="package://rulliera/visual/lifter.dae" file_stl="package://rulliera/collision/lifter.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
<!--joints-->

<!--<xacro:rulliera_joint name="base__rotary" type="revolute" parent="base" child="rotary" axis="0 0 1" limit_l="0" limit_u="6.2831" limit_v="2" limit_e="100" 
                        origin_xyz="0 -0.345 0.579" origin_rpy="0 0 0" />-->

<xacro:rulliera_joint name="base__rotary" type="revolute" parent="rotary" child="slider" axis="0 0 1" limit_l="0" limit_u="6.2831" limit_v="2" limit_e="100" 
                        origin_xyz="0 -0.345 0.713675" origin_rpy="0 0 0" />

<xacro:rulliera_joint name="base__lifter" type="prismatic" parent="base" child="lifter" axis="0 1 0" limit_l="-0.05" limit_u="0.28" limit_v="2" limit_e="100"
                      origin_xyz="0 0 0" origin_rpy="1.5708 0 0" />                                        

<xacro:rulliera_joint name="base__slider" type="prismatic" parent="lifter" child="slider" axis="0 0 1" limit_l="-0.857" limit_u="0.174" limit_v="2" limit_e="100"
                      origin_xyz="0 0 0" origin_rpy="0 0 0" />

How do I set the constraints on the joint without inserting two parents for the same joint?

There are plenty of tutorials on building URDF's.  Just google. You will need a rotational joint for each rotation and a tranlational joint for each translation. This is all trivial info that is covered in the tutorials. I suggest you read through some of the tutorials and get back with more specific questions if you then still have issues. A sketch also helps.

Maybe my question was unclear, but apparently there is no way to connect two joints to the same parent link. I was looking for a way around this issue.

Well, as said: a sketch would help to clarify what exactly you are asking. For an example of multiple joints on one link I suggest to google for e.g. a humanoid torso model, which has two arms connected to one body. Or google for parallel kinematics if that is what you mean.

I apologize, I wrote badly in my last comment. I meant to have two parent links for the same joint. Now, unfortunately I really cannot provide a visual description of what I need.

Please, check if the latest edit can help.

URDF must have a tree structure, so it cannot represent parallel robots and joints cannot have multiple parent links. However, there are lots of people interested in such functionality, and depending on why you need multiple parents, there may be some hacks or different programs you can use to get what you need. See here, here, and here for some good suggestions.
But do you really need multiple parents? I am not sure I 100% understand your use case, but would it work if the lifter was a child of the rotary instead of the base? or vice versa?
Then it would be a tree:
base -> rotary -> lifter -> slider
or
base -> lifter -> rotary -> slider

The problem with your configuration is that the rotary and the lifter are two independent links. Theorethically a rotation and a lifting could occur at the same time. I may be wrong, but I don't think your configuration solves this problem.

I think what @user42630 is trying to say is that you normally create a dummy link between links if you need more degrees of freedom between two links. As you mentioned, you can only connect one parent link or frame to a child one through a joint. But a link doesn't need to exist as a whole, it is just a relation between two frames. You can create the dummy link in the same position as the other, with another type of joint.

Your structure seems pretty serial to me: base, lifter, slider, cylinder.
The contraint on the cylinder having to be up is not part of the kinematics.

Where do I insert such constraint then?

These constraints come from collision I guess and may only be handled by a simulation or your control law.
URDF is about describing the tree structure of the robot and the joint limits.
